# Finding correlation between two data sets in R

Tags: r, correlation

**UPDATED DATA SET 2 and 1 STRUCTURE:** Sorry for this sudden update. I have two data sets. The structure of my first data set is (when using `print(matr1)` in `R`):

```
        month_year  income
 [1,]  "Jan 2000"  "30000"
 [2,]  "Feb 2000"  "12364"
 [3,]  "Mar 2000"  "37485"
 [4,]  "Apr 2000"  "2000"
 [5,]  "Jun 2000"  "7573"
          .     .      .
          .     .      .
```

**Thus the first data set has** **one income value for each month of each year**.

The structure of my second data set is (when using `print(matr2)` in `R`):

```
     month_year     value
 [1,] "Jan 2000" "84737476"
 [2,] "Jan 2000" "39450334"
 [3,] "Jan 2000" "48384943"
 [4,] "Feb 2000" "12345678"
 [5,] "Feb 2000" "49595340"

          .     .      .
          .     .      .
```

**So in this second data set I have `n`(say 100 but not constant all the time) number of values for each month of each year.**

Both the data sets have values month wise for many subsequent years(like for all the months for year 2000, 2001 and so on). Now I want to find the correlation between these two data sets but month-wise and not as whole. When I use the R command `cor(as.numeric(matr1[,"income"]),as.numeric(matr2[,"value"]))` then I get the overall correlation but I want the correlation per month rather than as a whole. **I want the correlation something like this:**

```
                  Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | .....
Correlation        x  |  y  |  z  |  p  |  q  | .....
```

The issue that I have is:

1. How do I get the correlation value per month instead of the overall correlation?

**NOTE:** I am not sure whether I should have posted this question here or on `Cross Validated`. I had posted a question for this data set only regarding an error in getting correlation and it was migrated from there to here. So please forgive if I am posting this on wrong place.

**UPDATE1:** After some suggestion I have modified this post to point in the correct dimension. First of all, the data sets as of now are in matrix format and hence the quotes. I can convert it to `data.frame` as suggested by some comments but right now I have been calculating the correlation by converting the columns using `as.numeric`.

Comment: I see you're using a matrix. `data.frame` or `ts` object would be more appropriate for these sort of matters.

Comment: Does each of your data sets have one income/value for each month/year? Then how do you expect to compute a correlation? Apart from that statistical query, your question needs a lot of other help, such as why is everything in quotes (A: you haven't read your data in properly) and how do I convert things to dates (A: see about a hundred other SO questions and/or install the "lubridate" package).

Comment: @Spacedman, everything in quotes because he has a matrix, and matrix can't have both character and numeric classes at the same time, so the coercion hierarchy was implemented here by default I guess.

Comment: @Spacedman I have done some modification to above post. I understand that by having only one value of month in each data set we cannot get the correlation. I have values for month for each year in both data sets(for April in 2000 as well as 2001 and so on in each data set and for each month in that way)

Answer (score 2):

May be you can try:

```
dat1 <- structure(list(year = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 
2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L), month = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), income = c(30000L, 12364L, 37485L, 2000L, 7573L, 
25000L, 14364L, 38485L, 4000L, 7873L)), .Names = c("year", "month", 
"income"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

dat2 <- structure(list(month_year = c("Jan 2000", "Feb 2000", "Mar 2000", 
"Apr 2000", "May 2000", "Jan 2001", "Feb 2001", "Mar 2001", "Apr 2001", 
"May 2001"), value = c(84737476L, 39450334L, 48384943L, 12345678L, 
49595340L, 84337476L, 34450334L, 48984943L, 124545678L, 49525340L
)), .Names = c("month_year", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))



 dat1$month_year <- paste(month.abb[dat1$month], dat1$year)
 dat1$month <- gsub(" \\d+","", dat1$month_year)
 dat2$month <- gsub(" \\d+","", dat2$month_year)
 dat1$indx <- with(dat1, ave(month, month, FUN=seq_along))
 dat2$indx <- with(dat2, ave(month, month, FUN=seq_along))
 dat1 <- dat1[,c(2,3,5)]
 dat2 <- dat2[,c(3,2,4)]
 colnames(dat2)[2] <- "income"

 library(reshape2)

 dat2C <- dcast(dat2, indx~month, value.var="income")
 dat1C <- dcast(dat1, indx~month, value.var="income")
 m1 <- as.matrix(dat1C[,-1])
 m2 <- as.matrix(dat2C[,-1])
 cor(m1,m2)
  diag(cor(m1,m2))
 # Apr Feb Jan Mar May 
  #1   -1   1   1  -1
```

Also, if you can merge the two datasets together, this could be done using `data.table`. Using the `dput()` data above

```
 library(data.table)
 dat1$month_year <- paste(month.abb[dat1$month], dat1$year)
 dat1 <- dat1[,c(4,3)]
 setDT(dat1)
 setDT(dat2)
 setkey(dat2, month_year)

 dat2[dat1, income := i.income]
 dat2[,month:= gsub(" \\d+", "", month_year)][,cor(value, income), by=month] 
 #    month V1
 #1:   Apr  1
 #2:   Feb -1
 #3:   Jan  1
 #4:   Mar  1
 #5:   May -1
```

#### Update

```
dat1 <- structure(list(month_year = structure(c(5L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 
4L, 9L, 2L), .Label = c("Apr 2000", "Apr 2001", "Feb 2000", "Feb 2001", 
"Jan 2000", "Jan 2001", "Jun 2000", "Mar 2000", "Mar 2001"), class = "factor"), 
income = c(30000, 12364, 37485, 2000, 7573, 42000, 15764, 
38465, 5000)), .Names = c("month_year", "income"), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")


 dat2 <-  structure(list(month_year = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 
 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Apr 2000", 
 "Apr 2001", "Feb 2000", "Feb 2001", "Jan 2000", "Jan 2001", "Mar 2000", 
 "Mar 2001"), class = "factor"), value = c(84737476, 39450334, 
 48384973, 12345678, 49595340, 4534353, 43353325, 84333535, 35343232, 
 4334353, 3434353, 5355322, 5223345, 4523535, 345353, 32235, 423553, 
 233553, 423535, 884455)), .Names = c("month_year", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
 -20L), class = "data.frame")


 datN <- merge(dat1, dat2, all=T)
 library(data.table)
 DT <- data.table(datN)
 DT[, month:= gsub(" \\d+", "", month_year)][,cor(value, income),by=month]
 #   month         V1
 #1:   Apr -0.7136049
 #2:   Feb -0.7037676
 #3:   Jan -0.8637808
 #4:   Jun         NA
 #5:   Mar -0.6484684
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but there is some update in my data set 2 structure. Now in data set 2 I have multiple values for each month but data set 1 still has one value for each month. I have modified my post above. How will the approach get modify now for this situation? Also, I have transformed the `year` and `month` structure of data set 1(and joined these two columns) to match with `month_year` structure of data set 2.

Comment: I am having a bit difficulty in understanding with what exactly are you doing in forming `dat1` and `dat2`? The data set that I have shown is a sample data set to show the structure and the values in those data sets are getting generated automatically, like from a database or a csv file. The values are not entered manually.Though the structure of data set is as I have shown. I apologize for a bit confusion that I am having

Comment: @Jason Donnald.  Your dataset is difficult to reproduce.  But, if you copy the one I showed, it would be easier to get the result.  I used `dput`.  For example, after you read the dataset i.e. `dat <- read.table("file.txt" , sep=""); `dput(head(dat, 20))` would give the structure.

Comment: that's the issue that the values are not fixed that I can manually enter like the way you have shown.And neither its specific that how many values will be there.Hence I am having difficulty in understanding how to form a generic structure with the kind of data set that I have?

Comment: @Jason Donnald.  The use of `dput` is for portability.  If you show your dataset like the way you showed and some columns are `character` columns, the reader may not be able to judge whether that column is `factor` or `character`.  Using `dput`, it gives the structure, and thus easier to understand the problem. Did you tried reading the data and `dput(head(dat,20))`

Comment: I tried using `dput(head(dat1,20))` and `dput(head(dat2,20))` and then do the steps as shown above but all I get a correlation result is `NA`. The issue is that in my data set 1 I have one value for each month of each year but in my data set 2 I have multiple values for each month of each year. So this difference in number of overall rows (either month wise or as a whole) is creating issues.

Comment: @Jason Donnald, I tried to replicate the issue in the updated dataset (which you can check).  Regarding the NAs, the correlation calculation depends upon standard deviation, which will be the one creating the problem.

Comment: Yes the standard deviation is coming zero and the reason for that I think is because of difference in size of data set(both month wise and overall). How can it be resolved?

Comment: @Jason Donnald. If standard deviation is the issue, you need more data to solve it.

Comment: but more data in which data set? My second data set has around 1000+ rows while first data set has around 100 rows. could this be issue?

Comment: @Jason Donnald, As you mentioned earlier, one of the dataset have only single rows for each month.  When this dataset gets merged to second dataset, it creates only duplicated rows.  If there is no variability for that month, this will affect the SD.

Answer (score 0):

Get your data into a data frame with month, value, and income columns. EG:

```
d = data.frame(month=rep(1:12,5),value=runif(60,10000000,60000000), income=runif(60,5000,40000))

> head(d)
  month    value   income
1     1 58348424 34478.63
2     2 59512513 16179.46
3     3 21844994 20961.56
4     4 25843593 38502.16
5     5 24805863 12397.32
6     6 24200966 24110.27
```

Then its as simple as using `dplyr` to group by month and summarize:

```
> require(dplyr)
> d %.% group_by(month) %.% summarize(cor = cor(value, income))
Source: local data frame [12 x 2]

   month         cor
1      1  0.17774478
2      2 -0.61693145
3      3 -0.05692027
4      4 -0.44966542
5      5 -0.30049386
6      6  0.09447414
7      7  0.67567298
8      8  0.14363810
9      9 -0.71899361
10    10  0.20807679
11    11 -0.42560100
12    12  0.23584150
```

Getting the month number from a date string is covered in many other places... but here I'd use the `lubridate` package. For the month/year strings in your second data set, for example:

```
require(lubridate)
month(dmy(paste("01",dat2$month_year)))
```

returns the month number. Note the trick of sticking a "01" on the start to make it a valid date.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but there is some update in my data set 2 structure. Now in data set 2 I have multiple values for each month but data set 1 still has one value for each month. I have modified my post above. How will the approach  get modify now for this situation?

Comment: Also, I have transformed the `year` and `month` structure of data set 1(and joined these two columns) to match with `month_year` structure of data set 2.